# pandas going from complex to float

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def wrap_fft(df):
        return pd.DataFrame({c:np.fft.rfft(df[c]) for c in df})

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=60, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(60,2), index=dates, columns=list('AB'))
a=df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('10T')).apply(wrap_fft)
print(a.mean(level=1))
print(a['A'].mean(level=1))
```

In the two last print statements I expected both of them to yield complex types, however, the first one returns floats and second one returns, as expected, complex types. Why is the first one returns floats and how do I prevent this from happening?

My version of pandas is `0.15.0`.

Thank you.

Comment: Might be, that the problem is that dataframe (`df`) is initialized as real. You should try forcing pandas to create a complex dataframe, either `df = pd.DataFrame(..., dtype='complex128')` or using `df = df.astype('complex128')` after initialization.

Comment: @matjazzz144 thanks for the comment, but I tried both your suggestions and there was no difference. This is starting to look like a bug to me. I'll update my question with my version of pandas.